# How to let users create a "custom" product and add to cart

Tags: bigcommerce

I am developing a custom theme for a client, and the client has asked for a customizable, user-facing product "creation" form, similar in form and function to [this pretty nice example from Ollie](https://www.myollie.com/onboarding).

My problem is two-fold:

1. How to implement this in the BigCommerce dashboard Products section?
2. How to then go about building this with Stencil?

My initial thoughts are:

*How to implement this in the BigCommerce dashboard Products section?*

This seems pretty straightforward to me, though I am new to BigCommerce. I am imagining creating a single "Customized Kit" product with an option set containing the different variants that can arise from the customization process.

*How to then go about building this with Stencil?*

Here is where I'm a bit more muddy due to my lack of experience with BigCommerce and the Stencil structure. My first guess is: I create a custom form component that exposes the "Customized Kit" `Product` object to the context and then, on "Add Kit to Cart" click, somehow matches the attributes the user just laid out with the closest product variant. From there, however, I am unclear on the specific components that may need to be extended, which event hooks may need to be called, and how to link the whole thing into the "Add to Cart" functionality (I'm guessing I just create a separate `add-customized-to-cart.html` template).

Thanks, and for reference I am extending the latest Cornerstone theme (2.2.1-rc.2).

Comment: Is your product builder more like a kit, where multiple items are added to the cart, or does it offer a customized product recommendation like the Ollie example? If the goal is to recommend a product, your app could process the form results and redirect to the appropriate product page (for example, you might have a product page for 'small, active, normal weight dog meal plan'. Once they land on that product page, the customer could choose their options and then just use the built in add-to-cart functionality. It would help to have more info on how your specific product works :)

Comment: Hey Karen, the product builder is more like a customized product, but _not_ a recommendation.We have a "custom daily meal kit" product (think Blue Apron), and, through an Ollie-esque form experience, customers can input preferences, such as how active they are during the day and what their dietary restrictions are, ending with a "Dluks's custom daily meal kit". There is really only one key preference that effects pricepoint (diet), so an option set should suffice for that, but I'm not sure how to best collect and store the other info and then report it well in the backend.